# Exception in thread, java code wont execute properly. If/else statments

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

```
// Alex Deines
import javax.swing.*;  


public class DeinesAdmissions
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String anwserString;
        double anwser;
        double y;

        anwserString= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your GPA", "GPA", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        anwser = Double.parseDouble(anwserString);
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your Admission Test Score", "Test Score", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            y = Integer.parseInt(anwserString);

        if(anwser>=3 && y>=60 || anwser>=0 && y>=85 )
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have been accepted");
        else 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry we must reject your application");


}

}
```

Exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3.2"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at DeinesAdmissions.main(DeinesAdmissions.java:16)
```

After I insert the Variables, I get this error code. Could anyone please lead me in the right direction?

Comment: You forgot to update `anwserString` in the 2nd call to `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`y` is `double` so use [Double.parseDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)): (same as `anwser`)

```
y = Double.parseDouble(anwserString);
```

You can compare doubles using [Double.compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-)

> Compares the two specified double values. The sign of the integer value returned is the same as that of the integer that would be returned by the call:
>
> ```
> new Double(d1).compareTo(new Double(d2))
> ```

Notice typo `anwser` should be spelled `answer` by @Katamari

You forgot to update anwserString in the 2nd call  by @JohnnyMopp

```
 anwserString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your Admission Test Score", "Test Score", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```